# Call to undefined function using encoding in PHP

Tags: php

i am getting `Call to undefined function basr64_encode()` Error of PHP is there some Library Missing ??? or any extension ?

Comment: do not fix your question after answer was given. Rolled back.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Noted and Kept in mind :)!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its `base64_encode` not basr64_encode
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Well you must vote up and accept it as an answer then :-) @PHPSeeker

Comment: Yep i was going to but i have to wait at least 6 minutes more  :) because i can accept as right answer after 16 minutes as Stacks giving me message

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) rather.